# iOS OpenGLES 2.0 Texture overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I'm Working With ios and opengl es 2.0, I'm going to draw a cube and texture it. When I perform texture and run my app the texture face that's in the negative-z is overlaps the face that's in positive-z and seems like transparent. I added the code below and nothing done

```
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

then I loaded some vertex and fragment shaders, but nothing happened.

Comment: Why does the IDE you are using for the development (Xcode) play any role in this question?

Comment: Well, it does not, hence I removed that tag.

Comment: @MostafaA.Khattab: that is not enough info. Could be everything.